# How to fix tooltip not readjusting based on tooltip height

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a tooltip that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBksP.png).

However once the tooltip gets long, the text wraps under, and then [this happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJ2gV.png).

How the tooltip is used: There is a wrapper div which has a component for which the tooltip is for, and then a div which has the tooltip:

```
//pseudocode
<div className=wrapper>
   {button}
   <div className=tip and position>
      tooltip text
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the css code:

```
// import some variables

.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.tip {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 4px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  padding: 6px;
  color: $white;
  background: $black;
  font-size: $base-font-size;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  z-index: 100;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.tip.long {
  white-space: initial;
  width: 150px;
}

.tip::before {
  content: ' ';
  left: 50%;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border: $tooltip-arrow-size solid transparent;
  margin-left: calc(#{$tooltip-arrow-size} * -1);
}

.tip.top {
  top: calc(#{$tooltip-margin} * -1);
}
.tip.top::before {
  top: 100%;
  border-top-color: $black;
}

.tip.right {
  left: calc(100% + #{$tooltip-margin});
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(0) translateY(-50%);
}

.tip.right::before {
  left: calc(#{$tooltip-arrow-size} * -1);
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(0) translateY(-50%);
  border-right-color: $black;
}

.tip.bottom {
  bottom: calc(#{$tooltip-margin} * -1);
}
.tip.bottom::before {
  bottom: 100%;
  border-bottom-color: $black;
}

.tip.left {
  left: auto;
  right: calc(100% + #{$tooltip-margin});
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(0) translateY(-50%);
}

.tip.left::before {
  left: auto;
  right: calc(#{$tooltip-arrow-size} * -2);
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(0) translateY(-50%);
  border-left-color: $black;
}
```

It should be something to do with position: relative or absolute, but I can't get it working properly. Also, as seen in the code, the tooltip can be positioned on the top, bottom, left, or right.

Comment: Can you post the HTML result and add some working example using snippet or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I think the problem is with your `.tip.top` calculation, the `top` style is calculated based on the `{$tooltip-margin}`, but what you need to do is set the top to be `(tip height + margin) * -1`